# How to verify JsonWebtoken error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token n JSON at position 75"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

I am writing logic for user registration and I want to enforce user to verify email before I persist data to database. The idea is to generate a JSON web token and send it to the client when a user registers. I then send an email with a verification link and extract the JSON token from the headers sent by the client or from the query params.
Everything works fine but when I run jwt.verify() it only works if the token is correct. For testing purposes, if I try to tweak the token it does not work which is the desired result. However it does not allow me to send a response to the user, in this case, it only thorws an error 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token n JSON at position 75', but works only if the token is correct. Is it a problem with my Javascript logic or this is how jsonwebtokens work?

helper.js

```
export default class Helper {
    constructor(){};

    /** generate jwt token */
    async generateToken (user) {
        return new Promise ( async (resolve, reject) => {
          const token = await jwt.sign(user, config.jwtSecret);
          if(!token) {
              reject();
              console.log('Failed to generate Jwt token')
            }
          if(token) {
              resolve(token);
            }
            else {
                reject();
                console.log('Somthing went wrong generating jwt token')
            }
        })

      }

    /** verify token */
    async verifyToken (token) {
        return new Promise ( async (resolve, reject) => {
            const isVerified = await jwt.verify(token, config.jwtSecret);
            if(!isVerified) {
                reject();
                console.log('Failed to verify jwt token')
            }
            if(isVerified) {
                resolve(isVerified);
            }
            else {
                reject();
                console.log('Error')
            }
        })
    }

    /** generate random string */
    async generateRanStr () {
        return crypto.randomBytes(20);
    }
}
```

routes.js

```
import express from 'express';
import Helper  from '../helpers/helpers';
import { Database } from '../database/db';
const Stylist = require('../models/stylist');

const router = module.exports = express.Router();

/** @POST Register new stylist */
router.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {
  /** validate user registration input */
  Stylist.validateInput().validate(req.body, async (err, user) => {
    if(err || !user) {
      return res.status(400).json({message: err.message})
    }
    if(user) {
      /** generate link token */
      const helper = new Helper();
      const token = await helper.generateToken(user);
      if(!token) {
        console.log('Failure to generate JWT Token');
        return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error' });
      }
      if(token){
        const emailSent = await Stylist.sendVerificationEmail(user.email, token);
        if(!emailSent) {
          console.log('Unable to send verification email');
          return res .status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error...' })
        }if(emailSent) {
          res.status(200).json({ message: 'Please check your email for verification link', key: token });
        }
      }
    }
  });
});

/** @POST Verify new stylist registration */
router.post('/verify', async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.query.key)
  /** verify token */
  const helper = new Helper();
  helper.verifyToken(req.query.key).then((verified) => {
    res.json(verified)
  }).catch((err) => {
    res.json(err.message)
  })

});
```

error in console

```
Application running...
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoiQ2xlYXJtaW5kIiwiZW1haWwiOiJjY2hldGVrd2VAZ21haWwuY29tIiwic3BlY2lhbHR5IjoiTm9kZS5qcyBZXZlbG9wZXIiLCJpYXQiOjE1NjgxOTgyMzF9.ZpKu_S4P9sOkFmzGD04ZIvbNJ8IFRXA80MT-kqC6ijQ
(node:8768) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected token n JSON at position 75
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.jwsDecode [as decode] (C:\Users\Tasman\Desktop\Project\beautify\node_modules\jws\lib\verify-stream.js:71:20)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Tasman\Desktop\Project\beautify\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\decode.js:5:21)
    at Object.module.exports [as verify] (C:\Users\Tasman\Desktop\Project\beautify\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:69:20)
    at _callee3$ (C:\Users\Tasman\Desktop\Project\beautify\dist\helpers\helpers.js:123:61)
    at tryCatch (C:\Users\Tasman\Desktop\Project\beautify\node_modules\@babel\runtime\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:45:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (C:\Users\Tasman\Desktop\Project\beautify\node_modules\@babel\runtime\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:271:22)
    at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (C:\Users\Tasman\Desktop\Project\beautify\node_modules\@babel\runtime\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:97:21)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\Users\Tasman\Desktop\Project\beautify\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
    at _next (C:\Users\Tasman\Desktop\Project\beautify\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:25:9)
    at C:\Users\Tasman\Desktop\Project\beautify\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:32:7
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\Tasman\Desktop\Project\beautify\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:21:12
    at C:\Users\Tasman\Desktop\Project\beautify\dist\helpers\helpers.js:149:34
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at _callee4$ (C:\Users\Tasman\Desktop\Project\beautify\dist\helpers\helpers.js:111:51)
(node:8768) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8768) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: The error strongly suggests you send malformed JSON data. Can you share the JSON data you sent?

Comment: That is the point for testing purposes I am sending a malinformed JSON token and ai want to send an error response to the client but it does not allow me to that it only throws an error and exits the process my logic is if(invalidtoken) {res.send(error message)}if(validToken){do something...}. but it only works for the second one, the first one throws an error and exits the process

Comment: plus you should not use async with new Promise as async always return promise use either one of them

Comment: @HemantRajpoot thanks that was the case actually all is working now

Answer (score 0):

I just downgraded my "jsonwebtoken" npm package to  "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1", and it worked for me.

*NODEJS SOLUTION